# Vue components / elements in v-html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `post.text` data that contains the text of a blog post submitted by the user Much like in Twitter, users can mention other users with the sintax `I am tagging @user1 in this post`. When rendering the post, I want to replace all the `@username` instances with links to the page of the mentioned user.

With a regex match / replace I can easily transform the mentioned `@username` into something like (I'm using vue-router):

```
I am tagging <router-link :to="{name: 'user', params: {userId: post.userId}}">{{ dPost.user_name }}</router-link> in this post
```

But when I use it like this:

```
<p v-html="preparedText"></p>
```

vue doesn't *reprocess* the html to bind its own tags.

How to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do sortof breaks the normal Vue paradigm, but it can be done using [`Vue.compile`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile). You'll need to use `Vue.compile` to generate the render functions and then manually create a new Vue instance
once your component has been mounted.

Here's an example:

```js
Vue.component('post', {
  template: `<div></div>`,
  props: { text: String },
  mounted() {
    let regex = /\B\@([\w\-]+)/gim;
    let username = this.text.match(regex)[0];
    let linkText = this.text.replace(regex, `<a href="#">${username}</a>`);
    let res = Vue.compile(`<p>${linkText}</p>`);
    
    let { render, staticRenderFns } = res;
    new Vue({ el: this.$el, render, staticRenderFns })
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { text: `Hi @user1, how are you?` }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <post :text="text"></post>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use `v-html`.

To dynamically render your components, simply use `:is="your component name"`.

Comment: That is not even what the question is asking