# Vue2 Router link from server data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, single-page-application

I have a Vue2 SPA page which is loading content from the server.
It is editable by client in a CMS.

When user is adding relative link (lets say /about-us), this should be picked by Vue and treated as the menu link (which already has /about-us link).

However link to /about-us added in the content is reloading the whole page, so it is not picked as vue route.

How is it possible to attach router to such links?

What I did so far is changing the content in the backend response.

So I am essentially changing

```
<a href="/about-us">Text</a>
```

into

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/about-us'}">Text</router-link>
```

Using:

```
function parseVueLinks($value)
{
    $pattern = "/<a([^>]*) href=\\\"[^http|https|mailto|tel]([^\\\"]*)\"([^>]*)>(.*?)<(\\/a>)/";
    $replace = "<router-link$1 :to=\"{ path: '$2'}\">$4</router-link>";

    return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
}
```

Still no luck.

How is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue components / elements in v-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584301/vue-components-elements-in-v-html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your issue is not with the link parsing, this looks fine. You want to compile the resulting HTML so Vue router can kick in. There is a function `Vue.compile` which can help you:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div></div>',
  props: {
    html: String
  },
  mounted() {
    let { render, staticRenderFns } = Vue.compile(this.html);
    new Vue({ el: this.$el, render, staticRenderFns, router })
  }
});
```

With this component you can specify any HTML using the prop `html`, which will then get compiled in the `mounted` event and will replace the component template. Please note the `router` being passed to `new Vue()`, this is a reference to your Vue router, which is needed so all the `<router-link>` tags in your HTML can be resolved.

Now you can use this component to compile your HTML like this:

```
<my-component :html="content"></my-component>
```

where `var content = parseVueLinks('<a href="/about-us">Text</a>')`.

You can see a working example over here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmmjwV

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Nice one! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think your replacement regex is good but is missing one `/`.
Indeed, after testing it, I see the result of parsing :

```
<a href="/about-us">Text</a>
```

outputs :

```
<router-link :to="{ path: 'about-us'}">Text</router-link>
```

instead of correct:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/about-us'}">Text</router-link>
```

(see `about-us` instead of `/about-us`)

Could you try this,please:

```
function parseVueLinks($value)
{
    $pattern = "/<a([^>]*) href=\\\"[^http|https|mailto|tel]([^\\\"]*)\"([^>]*)>(.*?)<(\\/a>)/";
    $replace = "<router-link$1 :to=\"{ path: '/$2'}\">$4</router-link>";

    return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
}
```

Comment: Still no difference. <router-link is not parsed by Vue. I still see it in inspect as unparsed element instead of `<a`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest regex pattern to do this is `/<a href="([^>]*)">(.+)<\/a>/`.

Test example:

```js
console.clear() 

const parseVueLinks = ($value) => {
  const re = /<a href="([^>]*)">(.+)<\/a>/g;
  const matches = re.exec($value);
  return `<router-link :to="{ path: '${matches[1]}'}">${matches[2]}</router-link>`
}

console.log(parseVueLinks('<a href="/about-us">Text</a>'))
console.log(parseVueLinks('<a href="http://google.com">Goooooogle</a>'))
```

I don't know PHP, but am guessing the equivalent PHP might be (tested at https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html):

```
function parseVueLinks($value)
{
  $pattern = "/<a href="([^>]*)">(.+)<\/a>/";
  $matches = [];
  preg_match($pattern, $replace, $matches);
  return "<router-link :to=\"{ path: '" + $matches[1] + "'}\">" + $matches[2] + "</router-link>"; 
}
```

I'm wondering about the presence of `http|https|mailto|tel` in your regex, does this mean you want to do some validation on the link?

If so, using `preg_match()` allows a second regex step to be performed on `$matches[1]` before output. It would seem simpler to validate as a second step rather than using one big regex.

---

### **Edit following comment**

> The issue is not in regex. It is in Vue not parsing content pulled from the server

This may not apply if you're using server side rendering, but this is how I apply links from content.

**MyComponent.ts**

```html
<template>
  <div class="row">
    ...
      <router-link :to="'/' + measure.link" class="measure">
        <i class="measure-icon fa fa-lg" :class="measure.icon" aria-hidden="true">
          <span class="title">{{measure.title}}</span>
        </i>
      </router-link>
```

Here, `measure` is an object that is fetched from the server. I you are fetching the full `<router-link>`, that may work with a [Dynamic Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) but it seems like overkill, since you ***know*** the element will be a `<router-link`.

Note, if there's also a problem with the server responding with **404** to the click, you can use hash-mode routing (default) by adding # before the link, e.g `#/about-us`.

Alternatively, set history mode in the Vue router.

```js
const router = new Router({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
})
```

This requires the server to redirect to `index.html` for a 404. See [HTML History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html).

Also, you then need to handle **404** in Vue with a catch-all route,

```
const routes = [
  ...
  { path: '*', component: NotFoundComponent },
]
```

Comment: The issue is not in regex. It is in Vue not parsing content pulled from the server. It has to parse my data and change `<router-link` into `<a` tags.

`http|https|mailto|tel` is there to skip links that are not going to be the router links.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I assumed because preg_replace was in your sample it was running on the server.

Comment: This question might be of use to you [Vue.js replace hashtags in text with <router-link>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274087/vue-js-replace-hashtags-in-text-with-router-link/47280673#47280673). I'll take a further look tomorrow. (Also note the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/movii/pen/WORoyg) referenced there.

Comment: One more thing, if the issue is preventing page reload, see [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html).